# How can I detect what proportion of a page has been scrolled through on iPhone?

Tags: javascript, iphone, xcode, dom, safari

I want to calculate what proportion of a page a user has scrolled down. My logic for doing this involves the following calculation:

`(pageYOffset + innerHeight) + document.documentElement.offsetHeight`

This should be (approximately) equal to 1 when the user reaches the bottom of the page.

According to [this page](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports2.html), the following inequality should always hold:

`document.documentElement.offsetHeight >= pageYOffset + innerHeight`

But when I run iOS Simulator - iPhone 6 / iOS 8.1 through XCode and scroll to the bottom of the screen, I get the following numbers, with `pageYOffset` actually exceeding `document.documentElement.offsetHeight`:

```
pageYOffset = 1809
innerHeight = 628
pageYOffset + innerHeight = 2437
document.documentElement.offsetHeight = 1577 // surprisingly small
document.documentElement.scrollHeight = 1577
document.documentElement.clientHeight = 559
```

When running iOS Simulator - iPad Air /iOS 8.1 through XCode, the inequality two values are much closer:

```
pageYOffset = 1286
innerHeight = 985
pageYOffset + innerHeight = 2271
document.documentElement.offsetHeight = 2270
document.documentElement.scrollHeight = 2270
document.documentElement.clientHeight = 960
```

Is there an explanation for this? Is there a better way to calculate the proportion of the page that has been scrolled through?

Comment: Would JQuery be fine?

Comment: Thanks @MohitBhasi, my approach below is based on JQuery...

Answer (score 0):

I've achieved the expected result by copying the [JQuery method](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/10399ddcf8a239acc27bdec9231b996b178224d3/src/dimensions.js#L33-L37):

```
var d = document.documentElement, b = document.body;
var documentHeight = Math.max(d.scrollHeight, d.clientHeight, d.offsetHeight,
                              b.scrollHeight, b.offsetHeight);
```

`document.body.scrollHeight` is larger than the other four fields, giving me the result I wanted.